# jQuery and chaining methods of .html().val()

Tags: jquery

I have some code I need to modify and rather than wrap a bunch of my code in if / else statements or create a custom plugin to determine element type is it possible to do the following without ramifications?

1. I have current code that is like this, which is good - it populates a div.

   ```
   $('#someElement').html('some text')
   ```
2. BUT, in some instances "someElement" is not a div or span. Sometimes it is an input field. So I thought to do.

   ```
   var st = "some text";
   $('#someElement').html(st).val(st);
   ```

This seems to work in my preliminary testing, but I am curious if there is a niftier way to accomplish this. I didn't want to do:

```
 $.fn.findEleType = function findEleType(){
     // do the figuring
  }

 $('#someElement').findEleType('some text');
```

Comment: no - AFAIK there is not

Comment: `$('input#someElement').val(myString)`?

Comment: Arun - you've been around the block a bit - in your estimation would .html().val() be a valid solution or hackish? better to do if/else?

Comment: .html() is to get/set the HTML of a selector (a div for example). Here's you're dealing with an input field; there's no HTML in an input field, just a value. So use .val() when dealing with input fields like this: $('#someElement').val(st);

Comment: hey frenchie - I understand. I think you misunerstand my need. The element can be either valid html element (div or span) OR an input. I will not know. It's random. so, I need something to cover both bases without doing a bunch of if/else statements or writing plugin. curious if there was a niftier way than ().html().val()

Answer (score 2):

I think you need something like this. Hope it helps

```
$.fn.findEleType = function findEleType(text){
    domEl = this;

    if(domEl.is("div,span,p")){ //etc
      $(domEl).html(text);
    }

    if(domEl.is("input:text") || domEl.is("input:password") || domEl.is("input:file") ||   domEl.is("textarea")) {
       $(domEl).val(text);
       // you can play with selectors like: "input:text:enabled"
    }

    if(domEl.is("input:radio")){
       // .is(:checked)
    }

    if(domEl.is("input:checkbox")){
       // .is(:checked)
    }

    if(domEl.is("select")){
       // index = $("option:selected",domEl).index()
    }
```

};

http://jsfiddle.net/2S34r/8/